# Change style of a single element in a loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

This might confuse but a serious question.

I'm getting table rows from a loop using php and I'm displaying those table inside a table tag using ajax.

Here for the each row there is an id called **productTableRow**.

So I want to do is, in this table when I click a specific row, I want to change that clicked row's background color.Just only that row and to take the value of the clicked row attribute called **product-id** and show it in another hidden input

```
$(document).on('click', function(e){
      if($(e.target).is('#productTableRow')){
        var productId = $(e.target).attr('productId');
        if(productId == productId){
          $(e.target).css('background-color','#128C7E');
        } else {
          $('.trProductTable').css('background-color', 'transparent');
        }
      }
```

});

This is my php code which generating the Table rows,

```
     foreach ($products as $product) {
                $responseData .= "<tr id='productTableRow' productId='" . $product->id . "'>";
                $responseData .= "<td>" . $product->id . "</td>";
                $responseData .= "<td>" . $product->product_name . "</td>";
                $responseData .= "<td>" . $product->product_barcode . "</td>";
                if ($product->group_id == 0) {
                    $responseData .= "<td>None</td>";
                } else {
                    $responseData .= "<td>" . $product->group_name . "</td>";
                }
                $responseData .= "<td>" . $product->product_cost . "</td>";
                $responseData .= "<td>" . $product->product_selling . "</td>";
                if ($product->product_type == 0) {
                    $responseData .= "<td>Liquid</td>";
                } else if ($product->product_type == 1) {
                    $responseData .= "<td>Weight</td>";
                } else if ($product->product_type == 2) {
                    $responseData .= "<td>Quantity</td>";
                }
                $responseData .= "<td>" . $product->created_at . "</td>";
```

Tried this code but doesn't work, really appreciate your help.

Comment: please add HTML to the post too.

Comment: @sid added the html code

Comment: Having multiple html elements with the same id in the same document produces unexpected behaviors, use a class instead

Comment: @KevinGuancheDarias how to make a click event if we use a class? and to the specific table row?

Answer (score 3):

After changing the id to a class, I would try this

```js
$('tr.productTableRow').click(function(){
        var productId = $(this).attr('productId');
        if(productId === productId){ // Always true
          $(this).css('background-color','#128C7E');
        } else {
          // Do something when false ???
        }
});
```

Edit Note: this code must be run after the table is added to the html, if you need to run it before, put the code inside a `$(document).ready(function(){/*code */ });`

Edit: Answer based on the comments

```js
$(document).on('click', '.productTableRow', function(){ 
    if(oldObject) {
      $(oldObject).css('background-color', 'transparent');
    }
    var productId = $(this).attr('productId'); 
    if(productId === productId){ // Always true 
      $(this).css('background-color','#128C7E'); 
    }
    oldObject = this;

});
```

Comment: this is not working as expected

Comment: It should, maybe you should put the code after the ajax call, if the table is not available when you put the code, It will not work, if you are using a manual ajax you probably have something like 

$.get('/my_server_code.php',function(response) { $('#table-container').html(response) })

So add the code I wrote just after adding the ajax responseto the html document

For example: 
```
$.get('/my_server_code.php',function(response) { 
    $('#table-container').html(response); 
    $('tr.productTableRow').click(......................); // put the code
 });
```

Comment: This worked after I did this,
$(document).on('click', '.productTableRow', function(){
        var productId = $(this).attr('productId');
        if(productId === productId){ // Always true
          $(this).css('background-color','#128C7E');
        } else {
          // Do something when false ???
        }   
}); , But this is changing the background color for the whole class I want to change the background for the clicked table row only and get the attribute value of the clicked row

Comment: @MishenThakshana I have updated my answer, with other way to solve your problem, please check

Answer (score 0):

First of all, id has to be specific to one element. Jquery is configured as this. Then you can use `$(this).parent(‘tr’)`
To get the parent row in the click event that can be to the entire class.

Comment: jQuery isn't "configured as this". The DOM / browser expects IDs to be unique. This is a general computing, if not worldly, concept.

Comment: Yeah but js and jquery excepts one element and this might be the issue here. This was my thought.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at my own answer,

```
$(document).on('click', '.groups-product-sidebar', (e)=>{
  //Getting the clicked group attributes
  var groupId = $(e.target).attr('groupId');
  $('.groups-product-sidebar').parent().css('background-color','transparent');
  $(e.target).parent().css('background-color','#128C7E');

});
```

Comment: If you are going to use es6 arrow sintax, you can use `const` for groupID instead of `var` parenthesis around the `e` are not required. Btw, I like the way you set  the objects to transparent, is clever than my provided solution, Good job!